# How filter data to print PDF file from comments table in Laravel?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I need print comments which related to each task from My task table in My laravel application,

This is pdf out put controller,

```
class TcommentPDFController extends Controller
{
    public function getTCPDF(){
        $comments = Comment::where('task_id')->get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.taskcomments',['comments'=>$comments]);
        return $pdf->stream('taskcomments.pdf');
    }
```

and route is this,

```
<li><a href="/project/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{$task->id}}/getTCPDF">Comments Report</a></li>
```

My comments table structure is like this:

```
id   comments  project_id  task_id
 1     frt         1          2
 2     ghy         1          4
 3     hgy         2          6
 4     lkj         5          9
```

My blade file is this

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $comment->comments}}</td>
    <td>{{$comment->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$comment->updated_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$comment->user->name}}</td>
</tr>
```

How can do this?

Comment: any help here...

Answer (score 0):

got solutions via this way My Controller,

```
class TcommentPDFController extends Controller
{
    public function getTCPDF($id,$taskId){
        $comments = Comment::where('project_id',$id)
       ->where('task_id',$taskId)
        ->get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.taskcomments',['comments'=>$comments]);
        return $pdf->stream('taskcomments.pdf');
    }
```